# not being able to query BusinessHours in Case object

Tags: soql, query, case, workbench, businesshours

I have set up Business Hours in my org. A field called `BusinessHours` appears in the `Case` Standard field List. However as soon as I try to query using workbench, it throws an error

```
select BusinessHours,Id from case
```

> **INVALID_FIELD**:  select BusinessHours,Id from case

Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation on [`Case`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_case.htm), you will see that the actual field API Name is **`BusinessHoursId`**:

```
SELECT BusinessHoursId FROM Case
```